# Why isn't .withSession in scope but it works fine when a trait?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm confused by I have access to .withSession when I have my getDb() method in a trait.

```
trait BaseDao{
  private lazy val db = {

    DatabaseAccess.databases("db.default")
  }

  def getDb() = db
}

class UserDao extends BaseDao {

    def getById(id: Int): User = {
        getDb().withSession { implicit session => 
            return ...
        }
    }
}
```

[DatabaseAccess reference](https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks/blob/master/frameworks/Scala/unfiltered/src/main/scala/DatabaseAccess.scala)

But when I inject a class that has the same getDb() method I don't have `.withSession` available to me, it says getDb() returns Unit:

```
class DbUtil {
  private lazy val db = {

    DatabaseAccess.databases("db.default")
  }

  def getDb() = db  
}

class UserDao(dbUtil: DbUtil) {

    def getById(id: Int): User = {
        dbUtil.getDb() ???  // .withSession isn't in scope
    }   

}
```

[You can see withSession here.](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/slick/backend/DatabaseComponent.scala#L293)

I want to move away from user a trait to passing in DBUtil, but when I tried the `.withSession` isn't in scope any longer.

Comment: I think you have another typo in your second example. The parameter you pass into the `UserDao` class is of type `DBUtil` (note the upper case `B`) while you actually want to have `DbUtil` (lower case `b`).

Comment: @edi ok fixed that typo sorry, but still stuck on why I can't access .withSession.

Answer (score 0):

From your second example, it's `getDb()` to be out of scope, as it's defined on the `DbUtil` class.

So if you want to access that method, you need to call it on the `dbUtil` instance:

```
class UserDao(dbUtil: DBUtil) {

    def getById(id: Int): User = {
        dbUtil.getDb().withSession { implicit session => ... }
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine for me.

```
class Database {
  def withSession() {}
}
object DatabaseAccess {
  var databases: Map[String, Database] = Map()
}

class DbUtil {
  private lazy val db = {
    DatabaseAccess.databases("db.default")
  }

  def getDb() = db
}

class UserDao(dbUtil: DbUtil) {

  def getById(id: Int) = {
    dbUtil.getDb().withSession()
  }
}
```

Maybe it's a problem with your IDE. Have you tested if the code compiles?